# Bash compare output of command to empty text string

Tags: macos, bash

I am trying to write a function that compares the output of a command and runs a loop until it returns nothing.  When I run it, it acts like the condition has not been met and the script is forever stuck in the while loop, even though if I run the command at the prompt it returns nothing.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Machine is Mac OS 10.9 which is why the syntax of su is a little funky.

```
stopvm ()
{
    su macadmin -c "VBoxManage controlvm tjfog acpipowerbutton"
    while [`su macadmin -c 'VBoxManage list runningvms | grep tjfog'` != ""]
    do
        echo "Waiting for the VM to shutdown"
        sleep 3
    done
}
```

Running at the prompt returns the following.

```
bash-3.2# su macadmin -c VBoxManage list runningvms | grep tjfog
bash-3.2#
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[ and ]` require spaces inside after `[` and before `]`.

But you can rewrite your `while` condition as:

```
while su macadmin -c 'VBoxManage list runningvms | grep -q tjfog'
do
    echo "Waiting for the VM to shutdown"
    sleep 3
done
```